# Axios request doesn't return a promise / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I have an api object that I create from axios with this line of code.

```
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3006' });
```

Then I export this call with this line of code...

```
export const editPost = (id, post) => {
  api(`/posts/${id}`, { method: 'put', data: post });
};
```

However, in the file that I use the call, when I try to use a .then method on it, I receive an error saying

```
index.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

Here is the use of the export

```
  const editThisPost = (authorName, category, blogText) => {
    editPost(id, { authorName, category, blogText }).then(res => {
      setPost(res);
      setEditing(false);
    });
  };
```

Doing some research that means that my export isn't returning a promise. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `return` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `editPost` method doesn't return a Promise to call `.then` on.

You should update it to return the promise:

```js
export const editPost = (id, post) => {
    return api(`/posts/${id}`, { method: 'put', data: post });
};
```